# How to I unload Resharper without uninstalling it?

Tags: resharper

How to I unload Resharper without uninstalling it? I need it for one project, but it interfers with another.

Comment: Is it in Tools>Add-in Manager? If so you can enable or disable it as you wish. I don't personally use Resharper so I'm leaving this as a coment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tools > Options > ReSharper > Suspend

Answer (score 3):

In Resharper 5, you can use the `CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+8` keyboard shortcut (in the Visual Studio scheme - not sure what it is in the IntelliJ scheme) to toggle the code analysis on and off.